# How to use the -c flag of vim?

Tags: bash, vim

Please tell me how to fix this bash command:

```
vim -c :%s/.*/="mv ".submatch(0)." ".substitute(submatch(0), "abc", "xyz", "g")/g
```

It is part of a longer script, so it is important to rename files with bash.

Comment: `vim -c ':h -c'`

Answer (score 1):

You need the entire argument to `-c` to be one shell word, but still parse correctly for vim.

Simplest is single quotes:

```
vim -c ':%s/.*/="mv ".submatch(0)." ".substitute(submatch(0), "abc", "xyz", "g")/g'
```